# How to feed site details on controller in dashlet in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

how to directly get SITE details (like ID and name ) on main() of controller js of dashelt in alfresco

i can use " Alfresco.constants.SITE" on FTL file to read site ID, but need to know is there any KEY to read data on controller

janaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a service on the Share side which provides that information, because the information you want is only held on the repository. As such, you'll need to call one of the REST APIs on the Repo to get the information you need

Your code would want to look something like:

```
  // Call the repository for the site profile
  var json = remote.call("/api/sites/" + page.url.templateArgs.site);

  if (json.status == 200)
  {
     // Create javascript objects from the repo response
     var obj = eval('(' + json + ')');
     if (obj)
     {
        var siteTitle = obj.title;
        var siteShortName = obj.shortName;
     }
  }
```

You can see a fuller example of this in various Alfresco dashlets, eg the [Dynamic Welcome dashlet](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/slingshot/config/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/dashlets/dynamic-welcome.get.js)